# Adding text to end of line using awk

Tags: awk

I'll quickly lay this out. The input test.bat files looks like:

```
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame001.txt

awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame002.txt

...

awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame405.txt
```

What I want in the end is:

```
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame001.txt AIRtrac_data_frame001.tst

awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame002.txt AIRtrac_data_frame001.tst

...

awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame405.txt AIRtrac_data_frame001.tst
```

This awk command takes the file in and prints the original nicely, saving the file name to be appended.

cmd:

```
 awk '{temp = $7} {printf("%s\n", $0)}' mactounix_convert_line_return.bat
```

output:

```
**awk '{temp = $7} {printf("%s\n", $0)}' mactounix_convert_line_return.bat**
```

The problem is when I try to append the captured string to the end of the line

cmd:

```
awk '{temp = $7} {printf "%s %s\n", $0, temp}' mactounix_convert_line_return.bat
```

output:

```
**AIRtrac_data_frame405.txtrint $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame405.txt**
```

It appears that the captured text ($7)is overwriting the original string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mac since OSX (i.e. 10.0) has used `\n`, so unless you're converting 12+-year-old files, you probably shouldn't need this. Have you checked whether the files actually have `\r`s?

Comment: (and not windows `\r\n`, in which case you should use `dos2unix`)

Comment: The files are being saved by a custom windows program using some .net API, so this question is quite real. I can't tell you the Windows tool set, but it is at worst 3 years old. So back to the question at hand.

Comment: Then it's windows' `\r\n` that's the problem, so use `dos2unix` like I said (or `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: I have already looked at the binary of the files and there is only a \r in the file. So are you saying that I need to remove the \r before I print out the original string in $0 ?

Comment: Kevin, I tried adding tr -d '\r' to no avail. Just to clarify, when I say there is only a \r, I mean a 0x0D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your requirement correctly but based on your input and output you can try something like this -

```
awk '{ a=$0; sub (/txt$/,"tst",$NF); print a,$NF}' file

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame001.txt
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame002.txt
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame405.txt

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{ a=$0; sub (/txt$/,"tst",$NF); print a,$NF}' file
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame001.txt AIRtrac_data_frame001.tst
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame002.txt AIRtrac_data_frame002.tst
awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' AIRtrac_data_frame405.txt AIRtrac_data_frame405.tst
```

If you intend to redirect the output to new `tst` files then you'll need a `>` (re-direction) operator too. You can add that in between your print statements.

```
awk '{ a=$0; sub (/txt$/,"tst",$NF); print a" > "$NF}' file
```

Comment: Yes you have exactly what I was trying to do. The original .txt files (all 400+) have the /r (or 0xD) at the eol. I had mistakenly made the .bat file (to correct the original problem) with Windows eol's \r\n, which Kevin helped me fix. I can now properly awk a "fixed"(.tst) file so I will be able to concatenate a single field $7 from all 400+ files into one file. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to replace the file extension in last record($NF) with "tst" and append it to the original text?

```
awk '{printf $0; gsub(/[^\.]+$/, "tst"); print "",$NF;}' data.txt
```

printf first because if you change $NF, $0 will also be changed.

print "",$NF   is to seperate the original text and the new filename.

Comment: Yes I do. I was trying not to ask to much as the original problem was really aggravating and I thought once it was solved I'd figure out how to swap out the extension. Thanks.